# Bom dia, Existe alguma propriedade para alterar o texto quando o mouse passar por cima do botão ao usar o hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.btn .titulo{
    color:red;
}

.btn:hover .titulo{
    color:blue
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn">
    <span class="titulo">
        Titulo
    </span>
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gostaria de mudar o titulo ao passar o mouse com efeito hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível usar a [propriedade `content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/content) para fazer isso.
Basicamente `content` muda o conteúdo de um elemento, logo é possível com o seletor `hover` mudar o conteúdo, assim por exemplo:

```css
.btn .titulo{
    color:red;
}

/* esconde o titulo atual */
button.btn:hover span.titulo {
  display: none
}

/* "substitui" o titulo */
button.btn:hover:before {
  content: ">Titulo hover<"
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
    <span class="titulo">
        Titulo
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava

Answer (score -2):

Você também pode usar javascript criando uma função que pega o o elemento texto e substitui por outro, então vc chama a função quando passar o mouse por cima do elemento usando onmouseover. Assim:

```
<body>
   <p id="txt" onmouseover="mudarTexto();">Texto<p>    
</body>
</html>

<script>
function mudarTexto(){
     document.getElementbyId('txt').innerHTML = "Texto que vc quiser";
}
</script>
```

Comment: olá Willian, seu código tem alguns problemas e sua resposta poderia ser melhorada para ser um bom exemplo futuro, vou comentar algumas coisas que podem ajudar: 1) é preferível usar só css quando possível 2) seu código não volta o texto ao estado anterior quando acaba o evento *hover*, vai te forçar a ter 2 eventos ou lógica adicional na sua função

Comment: 3) se usa eventos *inline* (`onmouseover="..."`) não é necessário usar o `getElementById`, pq o evento passa à função o evento que disparou o evento (pode usar `this`). E isso te obriga a ter um ID num elemento que não precisa, se remover o ID não funcionar o seu código. 4) não é recomendável atribuir eventos *inline* como tem o seu exemplo, era melhor usar `addEventLister` por exemplo, sugiro ler isso para entender melhor pq (está em inglês, não achei traduzido): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these

Comment: comentei no sentido de ajudar você e quem tomar como exemplo a sua pergunta, e assim tentar usar as melhores práticas para trabalhar com eventos/funções em javascript

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, ainda tenho muito a aprender.